# Python 0365 logging in with own identity and get calendar from user

Tags: python, outlook-restapi

My application has to get the calendar of a Microsoft outlook account and put these into a database. I have already mad this work when working with the on behalf of user authentication, but i cant seem to get it to work when the application logs in as its own identity. I have used the standard authentication code that is on the 0365 library site and i seem to be getting authenticated. When i go trough with breakpoints it also seems to get the schedule, but as soon as i try and get the calendar it gives me an error. The application permission Calendar.Read is also applied to the app registration and an admin has granted it.

**.py file**

```
from O365 import Account, MSGraphProtocol, FileSystemTokenBackend

account = Account(credentials, auth_flow_type='credentials', tenant_id=tenantid)
if account.authenticate():
    print('Authenticated!') 

schedule = account.schedule()
calendar = schedule.get_calendar(calendar_name='Calendar')
events = calendar.get_events(include_recurring=False)

for event in events:
    print(event)
```

**Error output**

```
Client Error: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/calendars?%24filter=name+eq+%27Calendar%27&%24top=1 | Error Message: Resource not found for the segment 'calendars'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\xampp\htdocs\Jimmy\python\receptie.py", line 94, in <module>
    calendar = schedule.get_calendar(calendar_name='Calendar')
  File "C:\Users\gebruiker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\O365\calendar.py", line 1924, in get_calendar
    response = self.con.get(url, params=params)
  File "C:\Users\gebruiker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\O365\connection.py", line 808, in get
    return self.oauth_request(url, 'get', params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\gebruiker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\O365\connection.py", line 797, in oauth_request
    return self._internal_request(self.session, url, method, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\gebruiker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\O365\connection.py", line 759, in _internal_request
    raise HTTPError('{} | Error Message: {}'.format(e.args[0], error_message), response=response) from None
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/calendars?%24filter=name+eq+%27Calendar%27&%24top=1 | Error Message: Resource not found for the segment 'calendars'.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

**URL output**

```
"error":{"code":"InvalidAuthenticationToken","message":"Access token is empty."
```